# Compare two array of object without knowing their type

Tags: c#, .net

I need your help ! I would like to compare two array of object. These arrays should be identical but not equally ordered.

**Context :**

I'm writing a function to compare to object tree of the same type. By reflection I check each property of first object with the second object, when :

- I find a primitive type I compare it and if a difference is found i
  keep it in a list
- I find an object, I call the method (recursively) on the two objects
- I find an array, I check the length if they are the same, I parse the
  array and compare each value with the method (recursively). **In this case I need     to order the arrays to be sure the object are in the same order**.

**Way I think of, but not realizable :**

- I can't override the equals method of the classes, there is to many
  classes and they are auto generated by a tool based on an XSD file.
- I tried to use the GetHashCode in an IComparer interface, but the
  GetHashCode work with the references, then the ordering has no sense.

Do you have an idea of how I can proceed with it ? I'm thinking of generating an HashCode based on the content but how can I do it generically ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are all objects serializable? Then serialize and compare the results.

Comment: Yes that's what I finally used, they are serializable (for XML serialization).

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution...

I implemented a IComparer, and compare my object from stream transformed in Strings (not so elegant but it workd well) :

```
    private class ObjectStreamComp : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(Object x, Object y )  
        {

            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            using (MemoryStream mx = new MemoryStream())
            using (MemoryStream my = new MemoryStream())
            {
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(mx, x);
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(my, y);

                mx.Position = 0;
                my.Position = 0;

                return (new StreamReader(mx)).ReadToEnd().CompareTo((new StreamReader(my)).ReadToEnd());
            }   
        }
    }
```

I can use serialization, because my object tree is marked Serialized (for XML serialization).

I use it like that :

```
Array.Sort(valueReferenceArray, ((IComparer)new ObjectStreamComp()));
Array.Sort(valueCreatedArray, ((IComparer)new ObjectStreamComp()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that comparing two object trees using reflection only will get you into trouble if performance ever gets an issue? You should always try to avoid reflection whereever possible, especially if you are dealing with large object trees. Reflection is OK for a proof-of-concept, but not really for more.

But what is wrong with overriding the Equals-Method? XSD usually does not generate you Equals-methods and thus you are free to extend these generated classes with your own stuff using partial classes. This is exactly what partial classes have been created for, to mic static and generated code more easily.

**Edit:** Note that if you override Equals, you also have to override GetHashCode appropriately. However, this means that all objects using your classes will use value equality by default. If this is not what you want, a custom `IEqualityComparer` as suggested by Alex Pashkin is a better option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of performance issue relative to reflection. I will use it only in test context, I have no need of good performance.
 I can't implement equals function for each element of the XSD, it's represent a too big amount of work !

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can implement you own IEqualityComparer

```
public class MyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
{        
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        //your code here
    }
    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And for example if you wanted to use it in exept you simply do this

```
var list1 = new List<object>();
var list2 = new List<object>();
var rest = list1.Except(list2, new MyComparer<object>());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In place of IEqualityComparer, I implement IComparer, more info on original topic.

Comment: You can't for Example realize Except with IComparer cause it's needs IEqualityComparer for it. For most of linq operations with two IEnumerable you need an IEqualityComparer and there are no sense IComparer